# How to programmatically create a call log based on DataValidation in Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, google-sheets, validation

Beginner programmer here. Working on a script for google sheets. Here's my scenario, if anyone can help with this I will be forever in your debt.

I have a call log, sheet name: PHONESHEET, where I've made an "entry bar" with headings "Caller; Phone No.; Status" across three columns. When a name and status is entered, it moves the row down to the appropriate heading (Need To Call, In, etc.). This works, no problem.

I have a second sheet called ARCHIVE where I have a long list of past information. In column A there are callers' names. In column B, there are the callers' corresponding phone numbers.

I have set up a custom dataValidation where typing into column A of my search bar on PHONESHEET checks the value against all the names in column A of ARCHIVE. That works beautifully.

What I can't for the life of me figure out, is how to get the value of the corresponding phone number in column B in ARCHIVE to automatically fill in in column B of the search bar when a valid name has been entered.

EXAMPLE:

On Sheet PHONESHEET: I start typing JOE SCHMO into the search bar at cell: (4, 1); It comes up with a smaller and smaller list as I'm typing and before I finish, it populates JOE SCHMO as an option based on that dataValidation. I want to be able to select JOE SCHMO and have his phone number, the number in the cell next to his name on ARCHIVE, automatically go into my search bar at cell (4, 2)

I've been messing with ifs and fors but haven't been able to come up with a solution that works

Your help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't understand too well your question, but I think `=VLOOKUP` is what your looking for.

Ex. JOE SCHMO in B4, Names in column D and Numbers in column E.

`=VLOOKUP(B4;D:E;2;FALSE)`

Comment: sorry but I'm talking about doing this all with a script

Comment: How 'bout sharing some script then...?